# Showing availability calendar in a line for an entire month for multiple items

Tags: javascript, calendar, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

what I am trying to do is the following:
[image: Calendar with availability for multiple items]

It would be nice if I could use fullcalendar or fullcalendar-scheduler but show rooms (or items) with their daily availability, not hourly.

I tried to extend fullcalendar-scheduler but was not able to show days instead of hours.

This is [fullcalendar-scheduler](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-scheduler)

Could you suggest a javascript library or something similar that I can work with (or even extend)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get something which is functionally equivalent, and visually extremely similar to your screenshot by using the built-in "timelineMonth" view:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'timelineMonth'
        },
        defaultView: "timelineMonth",
//etc
```

See the example here https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.6.2/demos/scale.html (click on the "month" tab). See also https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/ where the existence of this view is documented.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for :-)

Comment: no problem - next time be sure to make a more thorough study of the documentation! :-)

Comment: Just want to point out that your link goes to a paid component, not the free one. I would not use that paid one, but thanks anyway for your time. Still would be glade if you provide somethin else that is open-source that I can tinker with.

Comment: you specifically mentioned fullcalendar-scheduler in the question, and said you were working with it! So it seemed reasonable to use it. It's not necessarily paid either - if you're a non-profit, or your own project is open-source then you're not required to get a paid license. See https://fullcalendar.io/scheduler/license/. I don't personally have any experience with other similar client-side calendar software, as fullCalendar has always done what I've needed, and in any case recommendations of software libraries etc are considered off-topic on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic